# asp.net mvc how to bind to an empty checkbox value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am modifying an existing asp.net mvc application that creates a list of checkboxes from a list on the model, with property name "MyModelProperty" and additionally generates one more input element for "Select All" which has the following html:

```
<input name="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" value=""/>
```

What is the property declaration in the model that would create a boolean property that would bind to this existing element in the view?

I tried, 'public bool MyModelProperty_SelectAll {get;set;}' but it was returning null.  Is that because the value is an empty string in the html input control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Model` property for **string**:

```
public string MyModelProperty_SelectAll { get; set; }
```

Set some value for the `checkbox`, then in the server, if its checked, the **value** will be the given **value**, else you will see **null**.

```
<input name="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" type="checkbox" value="all"/>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to bind this to a bool, you must provide a `value="true"` and a hidden field:

```
<input class="input-validation-error" id="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" name="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" type="hidden" value="false">
```

This example code above was generated using the `Html.CheckBox` helper.

Comment: The application has logic in the javascript that depends on the "Select All" checkbox to have a value of "" so I was looking for a way to keep it as an empty string.  Any other way to get a bool property on the model in this case?

Comment: Well, just change the logic to validate the given value in the javascript, makes more sense!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use MVC htmlhelpers for generating checkboxes you must add an additional hidden element for your checkbox:

```
<input name="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
<input name="MyModelProperty_SelectAll" type="hidden" value="true"/>
```